# UIImage Quality Poor After Saving

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I'm working on my photo app and am having an issue with the final saved image appearing of poorer quality. I'm not sure what to do to get the image quality to match what I see on the screen (before saving to camera roll).  When i open up the saved image, it is pixelated/blurry. Here is my code, any insight would be appreciated:

```
CGRect grabRect ;    
    if (self.view.frame.size.height==460) {
        grabRect = CGRectMake(30,50,260,257);
    }
    else{
        grabRect = CGRectMake(3,50,314,315);
    }
    //for retina displays
    NSLog(@"save......");
    if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    } else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(grabRect.size);
    }
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, -grabRect.origin.x, -grabRect.origin.y);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have tried that and it did not make any difference.

Comment: Are you saying it's blurry *before* you save to camera roll, or that after you save it to camera roll and use iOS Pictures app to open it *then* it looks blurry?

Comment: After i save to the camera roll. It is totally fine within the app, but the quality is decreased upon saving and opening it up in the camera roll. It's not HUGELY blurry, just a little bit, but enough to annoy me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is the problem.

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

Should be
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(grabRect.size, NO, 0);

I may be wrong, but I think, just setting the scale to 0, or 0.0 uses the default scale of the screen.

Comment: tried this already :( made no difference

Comment: Setting the scale to `0` means to use the current screen's scale. Either gives the same.